# Keras ValueError: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer, attention-model

In my Keras model, I am using a TimeDistributed wrapper, but I keep getting a shape mismatch error. Here are the layers:

```
r_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(r_input)
r_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
r_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(200))(r_lstm)
r_att = AttLayer()(r_dense)
sentEncoder = Model(r_input, r_att)

input = Input(shape=(100,15), dtype='int32')
encoder = TimeDistributed(sentEncoder)(input)
l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(encoder) #-->>ERROR MESSAGE
```

And I am getting the error message

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer time_distributed_4:
>   expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

How can I adapt the shape of the encoder to match that of the input of the Bidirectional layer?

Comment: Please show the code where you create `sentEncoder`.

Comment: @jdehesa I added the code for sentEncoder, any ideas what I am doing wrong here?